# coloring cells which have same value

Tags: vba

I need to color cells green in column A if their cell value matches cells in column E. cells start from second row. values aren't sorted, so they don't match in rows. I need to check every cell in column A and compare them to every cell in column E.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
For i = 2 To 100
    If ((Worksheets("Table1").Range("A" & i).Value <> "") And (Worksheets("Table1").Range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets("Table1").Range("E" & i).Value)) Then
        Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    Else
        Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    End If 
Next i
```

- Just make sure you insert in the second line of the code the name of your table
- You can also change the number 100 to the number of rows you want to compare.

Comment: Did you change all 3 "Table1" attributes to the name of your table?

Comment: Yes, the code works now, I've changed some lines. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Giorgi Tsomaia: Would be nice if you can accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem?